# casperJS not logging to console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Learning CasperJS

Trying to understand why the following is not displaying my results in the console....

output:

```
casperjs testcasper.js
```

[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps

code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    loadImages: true,
    loadPlugins: true,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});


casper.start(url, function() {
    this.debugPage();
    this.echo("Test echo.");
    this.fill('form#LogonForm', {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.echo("I'm loaded.");
});

casper.run(function() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl(),'info'); 
});

//casper.log('this is a debug message', 'debug');
//casper.log('and an informative one', 'info');
//casper.log('and a warning', 'warning');
//casper.log('and an error', 'error');

casper.exit();
```

Comment: Is this issue with scope? :(  Same code runs fine outside of function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`casper.exit()` must be called asynchronously *after* all the steps having been executed; in your script, this gives:

```
casper.run(function() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl(),'info'); 
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: super, thanks!  I am trying to login into a similar form as here:   http://kprod.cc.emory.edu/wfc/logon
What should my script look like?

Comment: [info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#LogonForm'
[error] [phantom] form error: form not found

Comment: The site uses frames (look at the source); so you must open `http://kprod.cc.emory.edu/wfc/applications/wpk/html/kronos-logonbody.jsp` to access the form.

Comment: @NiKo How does this tie-in with the testing module? I have setup my options as follows
`casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel = 'warning';`

I use  casper.log("Sample Log statement1", 'info'); in my various test suites, and try to write them to a file in the final casper.run() method using phantom's fs module this way - 
fs.write("path/to/output.log",casper.logs,'w');

but my log file turns out to be empty